# regex with group names in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I started to play with python3.8 re lib and I find strange things.
First I'm making my regex online to test how it works and when I found out that its already working I try in python.

```py
test_string = [Tues Jan 20 11:35:13.405644 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 1871:tid 140301098780416] [client 192.168.123.9:59662] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/website/401.html

res = re.compile(r"(?P<Time>\w+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d{2})|(?P<Type>[a-zA-Z]+_\w+:\w+)", re.VERBOSE)

for line in logfile:
    line = res.search(line)
    print(line.groupdict())
```

I'm trying to parse log line like that like that. but I get the following result:

> type : none

I dont know why, or how to fix it , any ideas?:

```
{'time': Mon Jan 20 11:34:13, 'type': access_compat:error}
```

Comment: Try `r"(?P<Time>\w+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d{2}).*?(?P<Type>[a-zA-Z]+_\w+:\w+)"`, see https://ideone.com/HimnIT

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'

Comment: Do all the lines in the log file contain this pattern? You should put an if statement in before the print to see if line is not a NoneType.

Comment: See my demo. You posted non-working code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ur link doesnt work.

Comment: @tomgalpin yes, all log lines is the same

Comment: My link works and shows the same solution as posted by Valdi (just the quantifier is `*?`, not `+?`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a pattern with 2 alternatives, whereas you should use
a pattern matching **both** alternatives at once, e.g.:

```
(?P<Time>\w+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d{2}).+?(?P<Type>[a-zA-Z]+_\w+:\w+)
```

or

```
'time': (?P<Time>\w+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d{2}), 'type': (?P<Type>[a-zA-Z]+_\w+:\w+)
```

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/v6g791/1

Comment: Thank You!!! :))

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to work :

```
r"\[(?P<Time>\w+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d{2}).*\].*\[(?P<Type>[a-zA-Z]+_\w+:\w+)\]"
```

The code :

```
import re

test_string = "[Tues Jan 20 11:35:13.405644 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 1871:tid 140301098780416] [client 192.168.123.9:59662] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/website/401.html"
res = re.compile(r"\[(?P<Time>\w+\s\w+\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d{2}).*\].*\[(?P<Type>[a-zA-Z]+_\w+:\w+)\]", re.VERBOSE)
print(res.search(test_string).groupdict())
```

Result :

```
{'Time': 'Tues Jan 20 11:35:13', 'Type': 'access_compat:error'}
```

Explanation :

- You forgot to match characters `[` and `]`. You must use : `\[<pattern>\]`
- You have used character `|` between your 2 pattern. And this character means : match either A or B (e.g.: `r"A|B"`)

Source : https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Thank you too, i am still learning :))